# Twitter Bootstrap layout to "wrap" evenly on viewport resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, viewport

I'm attempting to create a responsive layout using Twitter Bootstrap. There is a "grid" of images (100x100) that I'd like to display in rows of 1,2 or 4 wide. I'm using a ".row" within ".container-fluid" and then span3 to contain each item inside the rows.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
             <div class="span3 product"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></div>
             <div class="span3 product"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></div>

             <div class="span3 product"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></div>
             <div class="span3 product"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
             <div class="span3 product clearfix"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></div>
             <div class="span3 product"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></div>

             <div class="span3 product"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></div>
             <div class="span3 product"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The problem is that when the browser is resized to certain width the layout changes unevenly. For example, when the viewport is between 769px and 795px wide I get rows with 3 items, and the following row with 1 item. I'd rather have "even" rows of 2 or 4 items. [See a demo on Bootply](http://bootply.com/59986).

Is there a way with Bootstrap out of the box, or will I need custom viewport calculations to get this layout?

Comment: After 769px all spans become 100% width. That's is your problem. I believe there is nothing out of the box of bootstrap to avoid that behaviour, you have to work a little with CSS.

Comment: I wonder if I can do this with @media queries?

Comment: You can do that with @media queries but it won't follow the grid. You have one option too, living on the edge and try Bootstrap 3 that has the possibility of putting spans for the small layout.

Comment: Something like that it's okay?: http://jsfiddle.net/eugip9/6taWx/ (I wanted to use Bootply but the CSS box didn't work :()

Comment: Seem to work for me on Bootply: http://bootply.com/60317 - but is there a way to use span3 in addition to product to use Bootstrap gutter, padding, float etc.. ? Thx

Comment: If you don't add `bootstrap-responsive.css` you will achieve that (but you won't probably want to lose the other nice features of the responsive design).

Comment: I just about have it working with a media query hack. I don't like using !important -- but it works: http://bootply.com/60772 @Pigueiras - are you going to post your suggestions as an answer? You're the only one who responded with an example!

Comment: No @Skelly. I think that none of my suggestions deserve to be an answer :). If you don't like to use `!important` you can use the selector `.span3.product`. http://bootply.com/60782

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the class of the .row divs to .row-fluid.

This will make it so that either 4 items are shown in a row, or only one if you scale down the window past a certain point. It will never do that thing with 3 items in a row.

Comment: I did use .row-fluid along with some @media queries to get an acceptable solution: http://bootply.com/60782

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just remove the  part in the middle of the code and let the browser handle the layout?  This will allow your items to be stacked properly, you could also specify a min width to make sure that you don't get too small.

Wrapping your tiled items in a row means that your items will always create a break on the new row removing it will allow the items that make the layout uneven float up beside the others.

Answer (score 0):

Change the class of rows, to row-fluid , like Vijay Ramamurthy said.

Or use isotope plugin  to fit your gallery as you want: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/